# Hide Lightning:Card on init?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css, lightning-design-system

I am having issues getting the style to apply on init.  It is working just fine, (setting visibility) on click, but is not having the same effect on init?

Component:

```
<lightning:card aura:id="card">
```

Controller:

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set("v.newTask.WhatId", component.get("v.recordId"));
    var today = new Date();
    component.set('v.today', today.getFullYear() + "-" + (today.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + today.getDate());
     helper.fetchPicklistFields(component);
     helper.getUserInfo(component); 
     var hideit = component.find('card');
    $A.util.addClass(hideit, 'hide');
},

handleClick: function(cmp, event){
    var cmpTarget = cmp.find('card');
    $A.util.removeClass(cmpTarget, 'hide');
},
handleLess: function(component, event, helper) {
    $A.util.addClass(component.find('card'), 'hide');
},
```

Style:

```
.THIS.hide {
display: none;}
```

Comment: Why don't you set <lightning:card class="hide" ...>? In that way you don't need to set it in an init handler...

Comment: can we see the whole component? I think your CSS is wrong.

Comment: You might consider using the platform-provided CSS class `.slds-hide` style rather than redefining your own. https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/visibility/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you turn this on its head: provide slds-hide by default, then remove it later.

```
<lightning:card aura:id="card" class="slds-hide">
```

Just because a class is listed in the component's original source, does not mean that the class can not be later removed.